# Python annotate type as regex pattern

Tags: python, types, mypy, python-typing, pylance

I have a dictionary annotation

```py
class OrderDict(TypedDict):
    name: str
    price: float
    time: str
```

The value of `time:` will always be formatted like `2022-01-01 00:00:00`, or `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. I'd like a way to express this in the type annotation

Something like

```py
class OrderDict(TypedDict):
    name: str
    price: float
    time: Pattern["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]
```

WIth the goal of IDE hinting through VSCode Intellisense and Pylance.

Are regex-defined type annotations supported?

Comment: I think you should a datetime object instead of plain string...

Comment: @DaniMesejo that is a good idea. Still, do you know of anyway to achieve regex defined type annotations? I think this would be useful in a plethora of scenarios.

Comment: May be you can use [`typing.Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Pattern).

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I've seen that but it's not clear to me how it works. There are not any examples in the PEP docs.

Comment: Type annotations annotate types. Your type is `str`. There is no more specific annotation.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM `Pattern` is for annotating a regex pattern type, not for annotating a string which can be matched by a specific pattern value. In other words, not related to this.

Comment: @zvone I disagree with that. This would be a *subtype* of `str`. The introduction of `Literal` already supports this sort of sub-type thinking, not to mention the recognition in philosophy/mathematics.

Comment: You can disagree as much as you want. It is not a meter of opinion. There is no way to annotate that. If you want to have a subtype of string, you can do that, but `'2022-01-01 00:00:00'` is not a subtype of `str` - it is a `str`.

Comment: I am not disagreeing as to whether Python supports annotating such a type. I am contending that it would be sensible and useful for Python to implement it in the future. I took your comment as less about Python's implementation and more about your personal philosophy about type theory/how languages should implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving out philosophical discussions about what should or should not be considered a type, what you are asking is not supported by the current type system.

It is valid syntax of course and you certainly can cook something up that abuses [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) to return dynamically created subclasses of itself. From a runtime perspective you can implement your desired logic without much of an issue.

But no static type checker will recognize this (not least) because it does not conform to the specifications that are currently in place around types in Python. As others have pointed out, from the perspective of the Python type system, a string (literal) is not considered a type and thus cannot be passed as a type argument to a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a type, therefore cannot be expressed and will probably not be supported either.

There is no difference between `"%Y"` and `"%d"`. These are both strings. The typing annotations exist to statically check types, not string formats.

The only cases which do not fit are `Literal`s, but they are relevant only for constants.

Comment: I didn't mean to specify `"%Y"` and `"%d"`, I'd want to do something like `Patttern["xxxx-xx-xx x:x:x"]`. As far as type/set theory goes, I think strings which conform to that pattern *are* a subtype of strings (just as "four letter words" is a legitimate subtype of all words) and think it would be nice to be able to express them. Literals already validate this notion, as you mention. This would be akin to dynamically defined Literals.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno But they're not a type per-se. It's interesting to discuss about it theoretically, but in Python the types annotations are supposed to prevent bugs that usually do not exist in static languages. Just like you can't declare a String in Java or C++ that conforms to a certain standard, there's no reason it'll be a special type in Python.